# Why my adding function does not work propertly

Tags: javascript, html

I've only started to learn JS. I had a task to make some basketball scoreboards. It is supposed to add a number to the score and change it whenever the user presses a button.

[image: Scoreboard]

```js
let guestScore = document.getElementById('score-guest')
let homeScore = document.getElementById('score-home')

let guestScoreNumber = 0
let homeScoreNumber = 0

function insreaseBy1(a, b) {
  a += 1
  b.textContent = a
}

document.getElementById('guest-1').onclick = function() {
  insreaseBy1(guestScoreNumber, guestScore)
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="header-con">HOME</h3>
    <p class="score-text" id="score-home">0</p>
    <div class="btn-wrapper">
      <button class="btn">+1</button>
      <button class="btn">+2</button>
      <button class="btn">+3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="header-con">GUEST</h3>
    <p class="score-text" id="score-guest">0</p>
    <div class="btn-wrapper">
      <button class="btn" id="guest-1">+1</button>
      <button class="btn">+2</button>
      <button class="btn">+3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I know how to do it using the function for each button, but I tried something like this to make only 3 functions instead of 6.

I expected that the score was gonna change, but it only added once.

[image: After pressing '+1']

Comment: The `guestScoreNumber` you are passing into your function, never changes. You only modify the value of the parameter `a` in the local scope of the function, that doesn't modify the value of `guestScoreNumber` in the upper scope.

Comment: in javascript you can only pass arguments by value and only when those arguments are objects they refer to the same object in the scope of the function called. So to keep the same strategy you adopted so far you should embed the score value in an object like `guestScoreNr = { value: 10 };` and read/write its value by doing `guestScoreNr.value` or if passed as an argument in a function call to `insreaseBy1(a, b)` `a.value`

Comment: As a side note, you write code to be readable for other humans not for the machine. More distinctive small functions are better then bigger but fewer functions. Bigger but fewer function reduce readability! increment with `a++` not with `a += 1`

Comment: In javascript, you don't really pass a reference to a variable when passing it as an argument, you are passing the value stored in it, which inside the function gets assigned to a new variable (the "argument"). Modifying that argument does nothing to the variable you passed in. So basically, you are better off passing a string key and storing the scores in an object that scores both. Then you can pass around the object, the key inside the object, and modify it as such.

Comment: Thanks @DiegoD. Now It works the way I wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, you don't really pass "variables" around, but their "contents", the actual values. So when you pass `guestScoreNumber` you are not passing a reference to that space in memory, you are passing the number it currently is in. But all numbers are the same for javascript, they all point to some hypothetical global number in the sky. So `4 === 4`, and doing `4 + 1` does not turn that global number into `5`, it just changes the connection to it.

So the easiest way to solve it is to pass an `Object` around. `Objects` are values that hold different references based on string keys, so you can just tell it to modify a certain part. It's either that, or referring to the variable directly but that makes for very unversatile code. I would suggest solving it with two objects and simply passing those around:

```js
const scores = { guest: 0, home: 0 };
const ui = { guest: document.getElementById('score-guest'), home: document.getElementById('score-home') }

document.querySelectorAll('button[data-target]').forEach(button => {
  
  button.onclick = function() {
  
    scores[button.dataset.target] += parseInt( button.value );
    ui[button.dataset.target].textContent = scores[button.dataset.target]
    
  }
  
})
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="header-con">HOME</h3>
    <p class="score-text" id="score-home">0</p>
    <div class="btn-wrapper">
      <button class="btn" data-target="home" value="1">+1</button>
      <button class="btn" data-target="home" value="2">+2</button>
      <button class="btn" data-target="home" value="3">+3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="header-con">GUEST</h3>
    <p class="score-text" id="score-guest">0</p>
    <div class="btn-wrapper">
      <button class="btn" data-target="guest" value="1">+1</button>
      <button class="btn" data-target="guest" value="2">+2</button>
      <button class="btn" data-target="guest" value="3">+3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```